# API not returning results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api

I'm using the [clarifai.com](http://clarifai.com) API. In my code below I'm using a sample image, the code is running through the Clarifai.getTagsByUrl() but it is not alerting the array. How can I have it output all the tags (I understand that I am getting an array, but it doesn't alert anything)? Thanks.

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https:///sdk.clarifai.com/js/clarifai-1.2.1.js"></script>
[..style..]
</head>
<body>
 <button onclick="run()">Click!</button>
<script>
[..js..]

    run(){
    Clarifai.initialize({
      'clientId': '{ClientId}',
      'clientSecret': '{clientSecret}'
    });

            // get a token
            function getToken() {
             Clarifai.getToken().then(
               handleResponse,
               handleError
             );
            };
          // get tags with an array of images
          function getTags() {
            Clarifai.getTagsByUrl('https://samples.clarifai.com/wedding.jpg').then(
              if (status_code == 200){
                alert(results)
              },
              if (status_code != 200){
                console.log("SOMETHING WENT WRONG");
              }
            );
          };


          getTags();
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does it console.log something went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for your getTags()

```
// get tags with an array of images

  function getTags() {

     Clarifai.getTagsByUrl('https://samples.clarifai.com/wedding.jpg').then(
       function(response){
         console.log(response.results[0].result.tag)
       },
       function(error){
         console.log("SOMETHING WENT WRONG");
       });
  }
```